# Controlled inputs and composite types

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It is easy to create a form with controlled inputs when all the model fields are scalar and mapped 1:1 to the inputs.

But what if the field is composite? For certainty let's say that the model has a `coordinates` property that looks like this:

```
{
    ...
    coordinates: {
        x: 10,
        y: 20,
        projection: 1234
    }
}
```

And let's say in the form there is a single text input that is used to manage this field.

So, I can easily initialise the input with serialised point as `(x, y)` (projection cannot be modified).

But as the controlled inputs mutate the model on every change - there arises the problem: what if the input does not contain a valid serialised point? Like `foobar`.

This string cannot be deserialised back to the `x-y-projection` and it's not clear where to store this intermediate invalid result, since the controlled element triggers the model change and re-rendering.

So my question - how to represent the data in this case and how it is usually resolved in your apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use **state**. The input component should only message its parent about a change in value once it has a valid value. You can set the child components state, to track the changing *invalid* values, then message the parent once you are done. It might look something like this. (here is a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/VejzbK?editors=001), note how the label doesn't change if you type letters into the input)

```
class PointInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, ...args) {
    super(props, ...args);
    this.state = { x: props.x, y: props.y};
  }
  update = (newValue) => {
    newValue = Object.assign({}, this.state, newValue);
    this.setState(newValue);
    if (Number.isNaN(+newValue.x) || Number.isNaN(+newValue.y)) return;
    this.props.onChange(newValue);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {'X: '}<input value={this.state.x} onChange={(e) => this.update({x: e.target.value})} />
        {'Y: '}<input value={this.state.y} onChange={(e) => this.update({y: e.target.value})} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have had the same thoughts and even though it looks like "a solution" there is a "problem" with it: the benefit the controlled elements bring is that what-you-see-is-what-is-in-the-store now is not valid anymore. So if a user clicks "submit" not the data from the input field that will be sent, but "the last valid data" which may be not intuitive. This can be resolved using the additional client-side validation (which may be tricky though, since now it's not only the store but internal components' state that should be validated)

Comment: You're starting to bring in other concerns, which necessarily change behavior. There are a couple ways to approach this. Validation can be done at the store level, but it can also be done by the component (perhaps by returning a `null` value when the value is invalid, so that store validation fails). If the store really does need the value at all times,  then you can separate the input from the parsed value. The store would contain a value for the raw input, and one for the serialized point (that updated once the raw input was valid). Then the input always reports, and ignores validity.

Answer (score 0):

Not depending on how do you hold your data (state/stateless), you can store invalid data in state/store and process it relatively in component's render method.

Any additional clauses can lead to a more sharp and complete answer